# Change values of a single column of a databound gridview and display it in the same gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Its a weird requirement but, Can I alter values of a single column of a databound gridview and display it in the same gridview ? Say, in GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e). I have edited the code for what I am actually doing. Problem is "DataItem" is a typeof class(entity fetched db table) and converting it to Datarow is not possible. So how do i go about it?

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (drv["Id"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                string val = CommonUtil.Decrypt(drv["Id"].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = val ;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: To be more specific, GV is databound, I just want to do some operations on one column and display the changed values in the same gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's doable in GridView RowDataBound something like:

```
if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

    //say you want to set value of 3rd column to "Hello"
      //  e.Row.Cells[2].Text="Hello"; //0 based index
     MyCustomClass myitem= (MyCustomClass) e.Row.DataItem;
     if (myitem.Id != null)
            {
                string val = CommonUtil.Decrypt(myitem.Id.ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = val ;
            }
}
```

If that doesn't help, please share some code and more information on exactly what column you want to change and to what value.

You can cast to the type you want:

```
 MyCustomClass drv = (MyCustomClass) e.Row.DataItem;
```

Comment: and how do I index the column "Id" ??

Comment: since it's the class object you can get it like regular member. e.g. drv.FirstName where FirstName is the a class property. Updated the code.

Comment: The issue is I get an invalid cast exception while typecasting,I tried returning the typeof(e.row.DataItem), it is something like :System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MyCustomClass_someNumericCode

Comment: Thanks , did not have to typecast, worked with the updated code.